# CMake + Boost + MSYS2 = "Can't find boost library"

Tags: boost, cmake, msys2

I've grovelled the internet for a solution and I'm stumped. Ultimately I need to build in multiple environments, and so far so good except for Windows. (I want to stick with gcc, so MSYS2/mingw64 seems like the way to go).

For this question I've stripped things down to the bare minimum. In spite of working at CMake and RTFM-ing for months now, I still find CMake opaque, so I expect I'm making a noob mistake. (Ha ha I'm an old hand at make, but that train has left the station!)

I have the latest versions as of this writing:

```
MSYS2: 20180531 
Cmake: 3.13.3
Boost: 1.69.0
gcc(mingw): 8.3.0
```

In order to guarantee that my Boost libraries are consistent amongst my various builds, I have downloaded/built them separately (instead of pacman -S boost, apt install boost, yum install boost, etc.). Ultimately the master build script will build the various flavors of the Boost library as necessary.

So I have a directory structure like:

```
~/x/boost/boost_1_69_0/b2-and-the-built-Boost-library
~/x/cmake/cmake-3.13.3/built-cmake-here
~/x/hello_world_cpp/main.cpp
~/x/hello_world_cpp/CMakeLists.cpp
```

My CMakeLists.txt looks like:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)
project(hello_world_cpp)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ON)
set(Boost_DEBUG ON)

set(BOOST_ROOT /home/me/x/boost/boost_1_69_0) # full path just to figure this out
message(STATUS "BOOST_ROOT= ${BOOST_ROOT}")

include_directories(${BOOST_ROOT})

add_executable(hello_world_cpp main.cpp)

find_package(Boost 1.69.0 REQUIRED COMPONENTS program_options )

link_directories(${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

main.cpp looks like:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/program_options.hpp>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

(Ha, just a boost #include, not even any executable boost code, but of course loading CMakeLists.txt still fails due to "Can't find boost library")

Here is the spew from the command line: cd ~/x/hello_world_cpp/cmake-build-debug; cmake ..

```
-- BOOST_ROOT= /home/x/boost/boost_1_69_0
-- [ C:/msys64/home/x/cmake/cmake-3.13.3/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1165 ] _boost_TEST_VERSIONS = 1.69.0;1.69
-- [ C:/msys64/home/x/cmake/cmake-3.13.3/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1167 ] Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED = TRUE
-- [ C:/msys64/home/x/cmake/cmake-3.13.3/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1169 ] Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS =
-- [ C:/msys64/home/x/cmake/cmake-3.13.3/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1171 ] Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME =
-- [ C:/msys64/home/x/cmake/cmake-3.13.3/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1173 ] Boost_ADDITIONAL_VERSIONS =
-- [ C:/msys64/home/x/cmake/cmake-3.13.3/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1175 ] Boost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS =
-- [ C:/msys64/home/x/cmake/cmake-3.13.3/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1243 ] Declared as CMake or Environmental Variables:
-- [ C:/msys64/home/x/cmake/cmake-3.13.3/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1245 ]   BOOST_ROOT = /home/x/boost/boost_1_69_0
-- [ C:/msys64/home/x/cmake/cmake-3.13.3/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1247 ]   BOOST_INCLUDEDIR =
-- [ C:/msys64/home/x/cmake/cmake-3.13.3/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1249 ]   BOOST_LIBRARYDIR =
-- [ C:/msys64/home/x/cmake/cmake-3.13.3/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1251 ] _boost_TEST_VERSIONS = 1.69.0;1.69
-- [ C:/msys64/home/x/cmake/cmake-3.13.3/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1326 ] Include debugging info:
-- [ C:/msys64/home/x/cmake/cmake-3.13.3/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1328 ]   _boost_INCLUDE_SEARCH_DIRS = /home/x/boost/boost_1_69_0/include;/home/x/boost/boost_1_69_0;PATHS;C:/boost/include;C:/boost;/sw/local/include
-- [ C:/msys64/home/x/cmake/cmake-3.13.3/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1330 ]   _boost_PATH_SUFFIXES = boost-1_69_0;boost_1_69_0;boost/boost-1_69_0;boost/boost_1_69_0;boost-1_69;boost_1_69;boost/boost-1_69;boost/boost_1_69
-- [ C:/msys64/home/x/cmake/cmake-3.13.3/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1460 ] guessed _boost_COMPILER = -mgw
-- [ C:/msys64/home/x/cmake/cmake-3.13.3/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1470 ] _boost_MULTITHREADED = -mt
-- [ C:/msys64/home/x/cmake/cmake-3.13.3/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1554 ] _boost_RELEASE_ABI_TAG = -
-- [ C:/msys64/home/x/cmake/cmake-3.13.3/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1556 ] _boost_DEBUG_ABI_TAG = -d
-- [ C:/msys64/home/x/cmake/cmake-3.13.3/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1619 ] _boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS_RELEASE = /home/x/boost/boost_1_69_0/lib;/home/x/boost/boost_1_69_0/stage/lib;Boost_INCLUDE_DIR-NOTFOUND/lib;Boost_INCLUDE_DIR-NOTFOUND/../lib;Boost_INCLUDE_DIR-NOTFOUND/stage/lib;PATHS;C:/boost/lib;C:/boost;/sw/local/lib_boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS_DEBUG   = /home/x/boost/boost_1_69_0/lib;/home/x/boost/boost_1_69_0/stage/lib;Boost_INCLUDE_DIR-NOTFOUND/lib;Boost_INCLUDE_DIR-NOTFOUND/../lib;Boost_INCLUDE_DIR-NOTFOUND/stage/lib;PATHS;C:/boost/lib;C:/boost;/sw/local/lib
-- [ C:/msys64/home/x/cmake/cmake-3.13.3/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1809 ] Searching for PROGRAM_OPTIONS_LIBRARY_RELEASE: boost_program_options-mgw-mt-;boost_program_options-mgw-mt;boost_program_options-mt-;boost_program_options-mt;boost_program_options-mt;boost_program_options
-- [ C:/msys64/home/x/cmake/cmake-3.13.3/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1862 ] Searching for PROGRAM_OPTIONS_LIBRARY_DEBUG: boost_program_options-mgw-mt-d-;boost_program_options-mgw-mt-d;boost_program_options-mt-d-;boost_program_options-mt-d;boost_program_options-mt;boost_program_options
CMake Error at C:/msys64/home/x/cmake/cmake-3.13.3/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2100 (message):
  Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.

  Unable to find the Boost header files.  Please set BOOST_ROOT to the root
  directory containing Boost or BOOST_INCLUDEDIR to the directory containing
  Boost's headers.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:19 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/msys64/home/william/krystallize/client/code/hello_world.cpp/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

I am grateful in advance for your assistance.

Comment: Well, you enabled `Boost_DEBUG` and obtained more information from the Boost searching than usual. That information includes list `_boost_INCLUDE_SEARCH_DIRS ` - where Boost include directories are searched, - and list `_boost_PATH_SUFFIXES` of possible suffixes for that search directories.libraries are searched. The include directory CMake wants to find is the one containing `boost/config.hpp` file. Do you have this file in your Boost installation? If yes, what is the **exact directory** which contains that file?

Comment: Wow, really helpful to know what it is looking for. Sadly, under `/home/me/x/boost/boost_1_69_0` there is indeed `./boost/config.hpp`, that is, the complete path/file is `/home/me/x/boost/boost_1_69_0/boost/config.hpp`. But it still can't find the boost library.

Comment: You might need to use a Windows-style absolute (e.g. path starting with `C:/`) when you define the `BOOST_ROOT` variable.  If CMake was compiled as a MinGW program, it can't understand MSYS2's Posix-style paths.

Comment: 'C:/' didn't help..

Answer (score 0):

In order for CMake to find your Boost libraries, you should rely on CMake modules provided by Boost itself (`BoostConfig.cmake`, etc.), instead of `FindBoost.cmake` provided by CMake. The trick to do this is to use `stage` command with a `--stagedir` option when you build Boost. Here is an approximate command line:

```
tools/build/src/engine/b2 -j16 --toolset=gcc --stagedir=$MSYSTEM_PREFIX --layout=versioned link=shared,static debug release stage
```

This will install Boost compiled binaries and Boost configuration .cmake files to the prefix you are using in MSYS2. Most importantly, (i) it will leave the multitude of Boost header files where they are; (ii) you don't need to do anything else, no magic tricks like `BOOST_ROOT` are required.

Comment: Don't MSYS2 Boost packages do this automatically?

Comment: Unfortunately, MSYS2 packages don't install Boost's CMake modules. I would be curious to know why. As of now, CMake's own `FindBoost.cmake` works well with the _installed_ MSYS2 Boost package. However, the question was about a _user-compiled_ version of Boost, for which the best mechanism of configuring your project is Boost supplied CMake modules.